Cannot load xmldocument using system.xml The '/' character, hexadecimal value 0x2F, cannot be included in a name
The xml document
<Root>
</Root>

This is the C# code where the document is opened:
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("path/to/document");

As far as I can tell, it is an issue with the file, as a different file is opened correctly using the same method earlier in the code.

Hi there! Please read how to ask for more information about asking good questions on StackOverflow. It sounds like your XML has a "filename" parameter somewhere and that has a / in it. File names cannot contain slashes on many operating systems. This may or may not apply to yours.

i'm pretty sure it is not an issue with file name, as when i remove the root node it gives me a no root node error.

I don't see how that's a helpful test. It's too bad nobody but you can see the file. Maybe it's the node name. Did you check that?

does it not show that the file path is correct? the exact layout of the document is



sorry i dont know how to upload it as code

The issue turned out to be in a different line of code further into the file.
Thank you for trying to help!
